# Building Gem - InvalidSpecificationException [...] are not files

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to build my own gem but got that error. I think the cause of this is **because I change the file name** of the `gemspec`. At first this is my structure:

```
myapp/
    my-app.gemspec
    documentation.docx
    // other files
```

Then I change the name and move files which become like:

```
myapp/
    new-name.gemspec
    doc/
        documentation.docx
    // other files
```

**Note**: I already changed all the code including the `lib` to fit the new name

Then, when I run `gem build new-name.gemspec` I got this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InvalidSpecificationException)
    ["my-app.gemspec", "documentation.docx"] are not files
```

It still recognizing my **old structure** instead of the new one.

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just realized that I must commit my new code to Git first.

Silly me.

Comment: Don’t forget to accept your answer after 48 hours, or, if you think your question/answer are of no relevance to future visitors, you can delete your question entirely.

Comment: I don't think this is silly at all. I haven't seen anything to lead me to believe that local gem development is reliant on git status. Thanks for posting.

Comment: The dependency on git comes from a common way of selecting the spec.files: `\`git ls-files -z\`.split("\x0")`

Comment: the minimum solution to fix this error is to add the renamed gemspec to the working directory: `git add .`

Comment: My problem was not committing, but I made a mistake in files options

Comment: You should be able to just stage a commit if you don't want to actually commit yet.